# How to define a class in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I want somthing that works like this in C++

```
#define PointCloud List<PointData>
```

wherer PointData is a small class which contains some data about a point and List is the generic List.

Greetings

//edit:
PS: Is there a name for the thing I am searching? If there is one, please tell me.

Comment: Closest is: `using PointCloud = List<PointData>;`

Comment: You can use `using PointCloud = System.List<PointData>` to create an alias available within that source file. But C# does not support proper typedefs which are available from other files. Depending on the context, deriving `PointCloud` from `List<PointData>` might be an alternative.

Comment: Thanks all! That was much easier than I thought

Comment: It is called "using alias directive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't mean class, instead you can use a "**Using Alias Directive**". The syntax for this is as follows:

```
using PointCloud = System.Collections.Generic.List<PointData>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using PointCloud = System.Collections.Generic.List<PointData>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new definition for PointCloud

```
class PointCloud : List<PointData>
{
}

class PointData
{}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to alias List<PointData> and not actually create a new class.

Comment: this is not what I asked for, but it even works better for my case, since I can use `PointCloud` in each script. Thanks!